# Cross Domain Requests Confusion

Tags: ajax, networking, web

I recently came across the fact that cross domain requests are not considered good. My question is that then how does my browser send login data to websites like Facebook ? Is my computer on the same network domain as Facebook etc?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that cross domain requests are not considered good?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: That just explains the security mechanisms for cross domain requests. Are doors not considered good just because we have locks on them?

Comment: Just keep in mind that same-origin-policy is enforced between the domain the page was loaded from and where it tries to get data. So if you loaded facebook.com it can get data from facebook, but it can't get data from google (unless google specifically allows it). Where your computer is has no effect on that.

Comment: thanks  ivarni  your answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The same origin policy applies to XMLHttpRequest and similar methods. Facebook and similar apps use JSONP to get around this restriction by exploiting the fact that this policy is not applied to script tags.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Edit: It works sort of like google analytics or ad sites that add code to your page from their server, but the code that they add with JSONP calls a function that you define on your code and passes the response as arguments, so two-way comminication is possible.